# Xcode 9.3 Git merge Issue after solving conflict

Tags: xcode, git, git-merge-conflict, xcode9.3

I'm Pulling some code from a master branch but it contains conflict with my code. 
There is only 1 file is in change and only 1 change in it and that contains conflict.
I solve it by selecting "Choose right then left" but "Pull" button is not enabling. It is still disabled.
I also got the same issue yesterday, but I ignored. 
Now Today again. This was working fine in Xcode 9.2.
Am I missing something or should I report this bug to Apple?

Here is the screenshot.
[image: Xcode Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved in Xcode 10.1(10B61)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Github Desktop application? The Xcode built-in version control system is not stable sometimes

Comment: I had solved this conflict via bitbucket's external merge tool.
But, I'm talking about git was working fine in Xcode 9.2, this issue is coming only in 9.3. I also tried to solve this in old Xcode and got success